# ActiveMQ: how to get consumer IP address

Tags: activemq-classic

In my project we are using Apache ActiveMQ to transfer messages between server and clients. We are using the `MapMessage` class to get the all consumer details. In the reply ActiveMQ returns all the statistics (`ActiveMQ.Statistics.Subscription`) like `connectionid`, `selector`, `clientId`, `destinationName` etc. But I'm not getting the IP address of the consumer. Is there any way to get the consumer IP? I can see the IPaddress of the consumer in the web console but we wanted to get this information in the server code.

Comment: In our project we are using "MapMessage" class to get the all consumer details. In the reply Activemq returns all the statistics(ActiveMQ.Statistics.Subscription) like connectionid, selector, clientId, destinationName etc. But not getting the IP address of the consumer. is there any way to get the consumer IP? I can see the IPaddress of the consumer in the web console but we wanted to get this information in the server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to get the consumer's IP address from the message returned by the broker's statistics plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response